# My app won't compile correctly on phonegap build

Tags: phonegap-build

My app won't compile correctly (.Myhelloworld-debug.apk) despite every 
trial and modifications I have done. Here is the link to the app: 
http://mrnk.hostoi.com/ and here it is on web: 
http://mrnk.hostoi.com/www , please I will like to know what I can do to
 arrange this app and get going.